# fastest and best way to add scrollbar to a widget in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a widget implemented with Qt5.0 but it is too large and does not have any scroll bars? how can I add it with minimum lines of codes?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html#setWidget ?

Comment: That's really nice way to add scrollbar but my problem was that I have to add my widget to Scroll Area and that's not interesting for me.

Comment: What do you mean it is not "interesting" for you? There are other ways, but all of them are more complicated and involve implementing the scrolling functionality manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to put your widget in a QScrollArea, you can make your widget a descendent of QScrollArea itself. All of the Qt item views do this (QListView etc).